# Getting overflow to work on 100% height div with background

Tags: html, css, height

I am currently building a website that uses two columns, inside a position fixed box to make the heights stay at 100%.

I need the content div to scroll down if the content is longer than the page (on 11/13" screens, page is responsive) - but by setting overflow scroll on the content, the background does not drop, and there is still content at the bottom of the page.

There are two links here, one is the page as it is, and the other is the page with extra content (to make it longer than your viewport)

[Link 1](http://toladverts.co.uk/davids/)  [link 2](http://toladverts.co.uk/davids/index2.php)

If you can help my solve this, i'll be thankful :)

Comment: @user3168736 [link](http://i.imgur.com/Vj4SOuo.jpg) - nope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `.bf_page` is set to `height: 100%` - this is getting the full height of the `body`, however the div doesn't start at the top of the page so it continues under the bottom of the `body` tag for 100 or so pixels, meaning the last bit of content is getting chopped off (hope that makes sense?!).

The height of the logo (which is causing the page to extend) is 121px so you could do the following:

Change `.bf_page`'s height to:

```
.bf_page {
    height: calc(100% - 121px);
}
```

Set `.bf_content_text` to `overflow: auto`

I've tested that and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add **Overflow:auto;** It works fine. I checked it with that page.

Comment: I can see a scrollbar there. Where would you want to add those scroll bars?

Comment: the scrollbar is in the right place, but the background doesn't stretch to the bottom, and there is still content off the screen.

Comment: If do , then add overflow property to that container. I assume content is below to that center div. so add overflow to it's parent

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the "position: fixed;" on the '.bf_menu' class works for me, if you're having trouble getting the menu to stick to the top of the page, just hide the blockquote div with display:none.

Comment: I have tried this, but both divs need to stretch to the bottom. [link](http://i.imgur.com/EWhRwH1.jpg)

Comment: You've lost me, do you mean the menu on the left should always be visible?

Comment: Not neccessarily, just the background needs to stretch to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="data">
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

#wrapper {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
}

#content {
    background-color:red;
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#data {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:80%;
    height:1000px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nGU8R/1/

Comment: Cannot for the life of me think where to put the styles from this demo - the code isn't mine, it's a colleagues. It's a mess, eh?